# How can I find the rank and spark relation here?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-equations, machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlRh6.png)

Hi, I can not get rank/spark relation correctly, I know that rank is a number of linearly independent columns of a matrix and spark is linearly dependent ones. In this question I understand option a), but I can not realize option b) and c). Could anyone explain that 2 option?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: [The same question was posted on Cross Validated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658070/how-can-i-find-the-rank-and-spark-relation-here), but then was migrated here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the rank and spark relation here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658070/how-can-i-find-the-rank-and-spark-relation-here)